# Cant create new project.. encountered an error

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

cant create new project on gatsby react..
`my node version: 12.12.0`

so after install the `npm install gatsby-cli -g` 
then created a project `gatsby new gatsby-test`.. 
i encountered some error

`ERROR

Command failed with exit code 1 (EPERM): yarnpkg

Error: Command failed with exit code 1 (EPERM): yarnpkg

- error.js:59 makeError
  [lib]/[gatsby-cli]/[execa]/lib/error.js:59:11
- index.js:112 handlePromise
  [lib]/[gatsby-cli]/[execa]/index.js:112:26
- next_tick.js:68 process._tickCallback
  internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7`

Answer (score 1):

I had follow the steps in https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-on-windows/ , particularly this set of commands on my project and it work after a few tries:

```
npm install windows-build-tools -g
```

then also:

```
npm uninstall node-gyp -g
npm config set python python2.7
npm config set msvs_version 2015
npm cache clean -f
npm install
```

Hope these help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're getting an exit code of EPERM, I suspect you've installed yarn as root. You *really* don't want to do that since packages have an opportunity to run JS as the user that Yarn runs as, and granting sudo/root privileges to JavaScript code you run from the internet is an exceedingly bad iea.

I suggest removing Yarn from your system, then reinstalling as a typical user account.